# Get YValue by clicking on a bar

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I'm using Achartengine to create a bar graph in my Android app. I need that if a user does a click on a bar, then he gets the value of the Yaxis. For some reason i don't want to use this:

```
renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
```

I wrote this but it doesn't work:

```
    final GraphicalView mChartView;
    mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
    mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // handle the click event on the chart

                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                if (seriesSelection != null) {

                    // Getting the y value after clicking BAR
                int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();


                Log.i("point: ", "is "+amount);

                }

                 mChartView.repaint();



            }
        });
```

I also added these to my multirenderer:

```
mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(30);
```

Comment: seriesSelection.getValue() is Y value but its double to convert it to int int amount = seriesSelection.getValue.intValue();

Comment: if i wrote your row i get an error. However here the problem is that i don't get the value on Log.

Comment: yea sorry , have a look here then http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-onclick-event-handler-for-custom-layout-linechart-in-achartengine/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Type.DEFAULT` to `null`. I am not sure why but its seems reason bcoz I tried and it working.Also see `mChart.toRealPoint` thing.

```
  mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        System.out.println("X :" + mChart.toRealPoint(0)[0]);
                        System.out.println("Y:" + mChart.toRealPoint(0)[1]);

                        SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
            if (seriesSelection != null) {

                // Getting the y value after clicking BAR
            int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();


            Log.i("point: ", "is "+amount);

            }

             mChart.repaint();

                    }
                });

            chartLayout.addView(mChart);
```